# Disabling Keyboard device from user level

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, linux-kernel, device-driver

How can I disable the keyboard temporarily inside a C program. What I have already thought is to disable the IRQ line(IRQ 2) for the Keyboard. I googled for it and found the 
`disable_irq()` function but it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<irq.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void main()
    {

         printf("trying to disable the keyboard via IRQ.....");
         sleep(2);
         disable_irq(2);
         printf("IRQ line has been disabled");
         sleep(10);
         printf("Enabling IRQ.....");

     }
```

When I run this I get this error:

```
irq.c:2:16: fatal error: irq.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Can you please help me resolve this issue or suggest any other method to do the same?

Comment: `disable_irq()` is a kernel function, there is no way to call it from userspace; what exactly you are trying to do and why?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't disable the keyboard from user space. I see no reason why you'd ever have to either. If you want your application to get all key-presses, try just being a fullscreen window.

If you're trying to prevent the kernel from getting emergency keystrokes, I'm never installing your application. THe keyboard is the fundamental method of communication between the kernel and user. The kernel uses it to get instructions, to get emergency recovery commands, and to tell you that it's panicing (flashing caps lock lights).

Even if you could, you should never disable the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `disable_irq(2)` from user-space because it is a kernel call, and can be called only from a kernel module or kernel code. Other methods to disable/inhibit keyboard are:

1. Unload keyboard device driver using `rmmod`.
2. Re-direct `stdin` to `/dev/null`
3. `#define scanf //NOP`
4. To disable only control chars like `Ctrl+C`, etc, use `signal mask`.